# Haskell Control.Arrow: trying to write a filterA function

Tags: haskell, arrows

I am trying to write a `filterA :: (ArrowChoice arr) => arr a Bool -> arr [a] [a]` function that removes every element from a list for which `f :: arr a Bool` returns `False`. This is what I have so far

```
listcase [] = Left ()
listcase (x:xs) = Right (x, xs)

filterA f = arr listcase >>>
            arr (const []) ||| (first (f &&& arr id) >>>
            arr (\((b,x),xs) -> if b then
                x : (filterA f xs)
                else filterA f xs
            ))
```

Now this works when testing it with `(->) a` Arrows, like this:

```
λ> filterA (== 8) [8,9]
[8]
```

It doesn't work however, for Kleisli Arrows like

```
λ> runKleisli (Kleisli $ filterA (== 8)) (return [8,9] :: [IO Int])

<interactive>:160:47:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO Int' with actual type `[t0]'
    In the first argument of `return', namely `[8, 9]'
    In the second argument of `runKleisli', namely
      `(return [8, 9] :: [IO Int])'
    In the expression:
      runKleisli (Kleisli $ filterA (== 8)) (return [8, 9] :: [IO Int])
```

And when adding a type signature `filterA :: (Arrow arr) => arr a Bool -> arr [a] [a]` or `filterA :: (ArrowChoice arr) => arr a Bool -> arr [a] [a]`, it throws this error:

```
arrows.hs:11:22:
    Could not deduce (arr ~ (->))
    from the context (Arrow arr)
      bound by the type signature for
                 filterA :: Arrow arr => arr a Bool -> arr [a] [a]
      at arrows.hs:7:12-51
      `arr' is a rigid type variable bound by
            the type signature for
              filterA :: Arrow arr => arr a Bool -> arr [a] [a]
            at arrows.hs:7:12
    Expected type: [a] -> [a]
      Actual type: arr [a] [a]
    The function `filterA' is applied to two arguments,
    but its type `arr a Bool -> arr [a] [a]' has only one
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `(filterA f xs)'
    In the expression: x : (filterA f xs)
```

I do not understand why. Did I miss something?

**Edit**:
@jaket's comment worked (I guess that was kinda stupid) but the type signature still doesn't match.
I also updated the code to be more compact (still getting the same error though)

```
filterA f = arr listcase >>>
            arr (const []) ||| (arr toEither >>>
            (filterA f) ||| (second (filterA f) >>> arr uncurry (:)))
  where toEither (x, xs) = if f x then Right (x, xs) else Left xs
```

GHC infers the type as `filterA :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`, by the way.

Comment: `runKleisli (Kleisli $ filterA (== 8)) [8, 9]`?

Comment: @jaket that fixes that I guess. However, it doesn't fix the type signature thing

Comment: In your update you use `f` as though it were a function in `if f x then ...` - that use of `f` is why GHC is insisting that the function typechecks only if the `arr` type is in fact `(->)`. See my answer below.

Comment: Also, note that @jaket's version of `runKleisli (Kleisli $ filterA (== 8)) [8, 9]` is not what you want - it's bound to the monad `[]`, even with a properly typed `filterA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to do the recursion inside the function definition that you wrap with `arr`, and you call `filterA f` as though it were a function in this line:

```
                x : (filterA f xs)
```

That only works if the arrow type is `(->)`, which is what one of the type errors is telling you.

Instead, you need to do the recursion at the arrow level, as in:

```
listcase :: [t] -> Either () (t, [t])
listcase [] = Left ()
listcase (x:xs) = Right (x, xs)

filterA :: (ArrowChoice arr) => arr a Bool -> arr [a] [a]
filterA f = listcase ^>>
            arr (const []) ||| ((f &&& arr id) *** filterA f >>^
                                (\((b, x), xs) -> if b then x:xs else xs))
```

(which does compile)

Your `runKleisli` example is a bit confused, you meant to say:

```
runKleisli (filterA $ Kleisli $ return . (== 8)) [8,9]
```

or

```
runKleisli (filterA $ arr (== 8)) [8,9] :: IO [Int]
```

That's straight from looking at the types.

Comment: Thank you, that works. I've rewritten the function to use toEither like this: `filterA f = arr listcase >>>
            arr (const []) ||| ((f &&& arr id) *** filterA f >>^
            toEither >>> (arr id ||| (arr uncurry (:))))` and
`toEither ((True, x), xs) = Right (x, xs)`
`toEither ((False, _), xs) = Left xs` and I've observed some behaviour that I don't completely understand. The version using `>>^ toEither` works, while a version using `>>> arr toEither` doesn't compile. But isn't `>>^` defined as `a >>^ f = a >>> arr f`?

Comment: Your complilation woes are coming from other things far away from what you changed not having the types you think they do. You want `arr (uncurry (:))` or `(arr $ uncurry (:))` - that is, don't apply `arr` directly to `uncurry`. If you do that, then both the `>>> arr toEither` and `>>^ toEither` variants will compile as expected

Comment: If you're trying to work with generic arrows, since both `>>^` and `>>>` associate to the right (that is, both are `infixr 1`), you want to be careful about expressions of the form `a >>^ b >>> c` , that is where there's any `>>>` to the right of `>>^`, since that means the same as `a >>^ (b >>> c)`, and so the `c` arrow will be used in the `(->)` arrow instance, and not the general arrow the whole function is in.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement the other answers: Using the [Arrow syntax](https://www.haskell.org/arrows/syntax.html) (see also the GHC manual, Chapter [Arrow notation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/arrow-notation.html)) you can write function somewhat more readable:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}

import Control.Arrow

filterA :: (ArrowChoice arr) => arr a Bool -> arr [a] [a]
filterA f = farr
  where
    farr = proc xs ->
            case xs of
                []       -> returnA -< []
                (x:xs')  -> do
                    b   <- f    -< x
                    ys' <- farr -< xs'
                    returnA -< if b then x : ys' else ys'
```

The result translated internally to the arrow notation will be probably somewhat less concise, but hopefully the compiler will optimize for you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment:

```
runKleisli (Kleisli $ filterA (== 8)) [8, 9]
```

Next you need to lift `f :: a -> b` into an arrow `arr a b`

```
(first (arr f &&& arr id)
        ^^^
```

in your function:

```
filterA :: ArrowChoice arr => (a -> Bool) -> arr [a] [a]
filterA f = arr listcase >>>
            arr (const []) ||| (first (f &&& arr id) >>>
            arr (\((b,x),xs) -> if b then
                x : (filterA f xs)
                else filterA f xs
            ))
```

Comment: But by the type signature I supplied in my post, `f` would already be an arrow. How would I go about that?

Comment: oh wait. I see what you're talking about. give me a sec.